# Docker error "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509 certifacte not valid for registry-1.docker.io in macOS

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am setting up the airflow in my macOS using Docker and I am encountering this below error while doing the setup. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ERROR: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509: certificate is valid for *.integration.livongo.com, integration.livongo.com, not registry-1.docker.io
```

Thanks.

Comment: Something is horribly broken on your network and requests to docker hub are not being sent to docker hub.

Comment: check your /etc/resolv.conf file, may be you have livango's ip there instead of docker.io's

Comment: Just also had this and restarting docker daemon fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue this week when upgrading to the latest Docker Desktop 4.4.4.

I am behind a company proxy which injects it's own CA certificate which can cause this problem. If that is your case, make sure you know what is the http & https proxy URL or IP if there is one, and add it in the Docker Desktop settings, under Resources/Proxies.

You may also add the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables to your system with the full url,IP of the proxy server.

If the problem persists, roll back to a previous version of Docker Desktop. That's what I ended up doing in the end because the latest version didn't work with my proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of default Enable of docker-compose command to use Docker Compose V2

**To disable Docker Compose V2:**

Docker Settings > General > Use Docker Compose V2 ( UNCHECK the box )

This should resolve your error.. Happy Coding :)

Comment: There is no error code telling about there is docker compose version issue in the question. Please recheck your answer that suites to this question.